# How to sort My/SQL data into groups on separate pages

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been reading and testing but no luck.

What I'm trying to do is group my specific data from my database onto separate pages when a specific link is clicked.

[Here is my DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bRHm.png)

For example, I want to sort the column "role" into links that when clicked will only bring up all the supports or tanks.

[role column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXUDJ.png)

I've tried order by as well as this function I attempted to make:

```
function get_image_by_role($role) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT id, main_img, main_img_thumb, name, role, release_year, realm, race, description, quote, img_type FROM champion_catalog WHERE role = support";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
    if ($stmt) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $role);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,
            $id,
            $main_img,
            $main_img_thumb,
            $name,
            $role,
            $release_year,
            $realm,
            $race,
            $description,
            $quote,
            $img_type,
        );

        $result = [];
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $result = [
                'id' => $id, 
                'main_img' => $main_img,
                'main_img_thumb' => $main_img_thumb,
                'name' => $name,
                'role' => $role,
                'release_year' => $release_year,
                'realm' => $realm,
                'race' => $race,
                'description' => $description,
                'quote' => $quote,
                'img_type' => $img_type
            ];
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $result;

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure if that's even correct or can be used when a link is clicked. I'm able to get a single character page by getting the ID, but I need a page for each type of role. Still learning PHP so thanks in advance.

Comment: We're all still learning. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking, but I think you’re confusing the issue with talking about sorting. It doesn’t matter in what order you present the list, you just have to pass the right information in the url. Read the link Strawberry gave, and provide some sample data and results. Otherwise it’s hard to guess what you’re doing. BTW, when you iterate through the database results, use an array `$result[]=[ ...results...]`; as written you’ll get just the last row.